# Recover a deleted file in VIM after running dG

Tags: vim

I was smart enough to run the `dG` command in vim and instead of simply quitting my muscle memory put in a `:wq`.

Is there any way to restore the file?

Comment: Press `u` for undo?

Comment: I quit and and wrote with `:wq`

Comment: Okay... I thought you didn't quit because you wrote "instead of quitting".

Comment: yeah ... corrected the original question ... but I guess there is no remedy here.

Comment: @Xen_mar Currently no. But for the future: configure [persistent undo](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#persistent-undo). With it you can quit, start a new session and still can undo things done in previous sessions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redo after reopening a file in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676668/redo-after-reopening-a-file-in-vim)

Comment: BTW if you have configured [viminfo](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'viminfo') to save registers chances are you can re-edit the file and paste deleted text.

Answer (score 1):

`d<motion>` cuts the text covered by `<motion>` into the unnamed register, `"`. Assuming you have a relatively "normal" setup, Vim should have written the content of that register to `~/.viminfo` when you did `:wq`. If so, you should be able to edit the same file and put the content of that register back into the buffer.

1. Edit your file in a new Vim session:

   ```
   $ vim filename
   ```

   The buffer should be empty.
2. Inspect the content of every register with `:registers` to see if it is still stored. If you didn't use Vim in the mean time, register `"` should have it.
3. If it is there, do the following, starting from normal mode:

   ```
    v                       " start visual mode
    "<name of register>p    " put from register <name of register>
   ```